# Using Bootstrap for Html Service

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, google-apps-script

i have to create a HTML dialog in Spreadsheet app.is it possible can i use twitter Bootstrap is it pass restriction of NATIVE or EMULATED mode and can be used for designing ??

Comment: can't someone reply to this easy question ??in yes or no ??

Comment: yes tried 2 minutes before included the library giving no error now using javascript functions.if possible please reply to this query http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19541269/sciptlet-is-not-rendering-as-expected

Answer (score 2):

Even in Native mode, using Bootstrap 3, containers and columns don't seem to style correctly (and the row/column structure is ignored), though the jumbotron does style fairly well and other elements may also (note: I've only tried in Native mode). I've not tested the JavaScript, since I've never used the Bootstrap JavaScript before, but depending on the features you want, you may be better off going with the jQuery UI library since it's supported.

There is a project for importing a version of Bootstrap 2 into Google Apps Script HtmlService, but I've not gotten the scaffolding features to work (though I haven't spent much time trying/debugging):

https://sites.google.com/site/gashackja/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Bootstrap just to format a HTML dialog, it may be overkill. You may want to try something lighter like [Responsive Grid System](http://www.responsivegridsystem.com/) (http://www.responsivegridsystem.com/) with the [add-on.css](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/css) file provided by Google. That's what I use. (You just have to remove the code for the 480px full width.)