# sciptlet is not rendering as expected

Tags: google-apps-script

i read the documentation i write an html page with code

```
<?= include('bootstrap-picker'); ?>
<div>
<script type = "text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"></link>
<select class="selectpicker">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<script type="text/javascript">
</script>
</div>
```

there is a method named include in code.gs

```
function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)
      .getContent();
}
```

and there is html file named as bootstrap-picker.html but whe n the dialog rendered.its giving me dialog

[image: Dialog]

why this scriptlet is not transformed ?? please guideline !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely, because you need to use `createTemplateFromFile(filename).evaluate()` instead of `createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)` in your `doGet` function. I highly recommend setting the sandbox mode to Native if you haven't already.

Also, if bootstrap-picker is a plugin for Bootstrap, `<?= include('bootstrap-picker'); ?>` will need to go after the script tags for jQuery and Bootstrap.

Comment: HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index')
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.NATIVE); i know only one method of setting sandbox mode native that is from createOutputFromFile how to make it native using createTemplateFromFile(filename) please give a small clue

Comment: `HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index').evaluate().setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.NATIVE);` - the `evaluate()` runs the scriptlets and returns HtmlOutput like createHTMLOutputFromFile